# Ending child process without returning a value

Tags: c

I am basically creating a function which calls upon a unix built in function and redirect its output to `"myexec.txt"`. So i called on `open` and `dup2` in the child process. They redirect the output of `execve` to `"myexec.txt"`. Upon calling `execve`, the child process is terminated and every other standard output after the execution of `execve` will now be directed to the terminal. I am seeking a way to terminate the child process in case of an unsuccesul call to `execve`, in order to stop the output redirection to `myexec.txt`. I know using `exit` works but is there a way to kill this process without returning a value? My function needs to return `void`.

Here is my code chunk. I purposely give `execve` a non existent path.

```
void myexec()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        printf("executing ls\n");
        char *argv[] = {"ls", 0};
        int fd = open("myexec.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        dup2(fd, 1);
        dup2(fd, 2);
        close(fd);
        execve("/bsin/ls", &argv[0], NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute");
        ......
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Function execution have been attempted");
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between "a function returning a value" and "a process returning a value"?

Comment: I believe I do. `myexec` is a function which returns no value. when running the function, it creates a process. fork creates two processes. `execve`replaces the calling child process. Whatever is returned by this new process is a process returning a value. Do correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Sure. But you said that you need the *process* to not return a value because the *function* returns void. That's a bit like asking "I know I can use the volume knob on my speakers, but how can I make sure they won't go louder than 600 litres? My fridge has a volume of 600 litres.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `exit`. That's a serious mistake that has caused severe bugs in the past with significant security implications.

Call `_exit`. You can pass it a zero, it doesn't matter if the parent doesn't care whether the child succeeded or failed. Since `_exit` is guaranteed not to return, you don't need to put anything else after that.

```
if(pid == 0)
{
    printf("executing ls\n");
    char *argv[] = {"ls", 0};
    int fd = open("myexec.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    dup2(fd, 1);
    dup2(fd, 2);
    close(fd);
    execve("/bsin/ls", &argv[0], NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute");
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some links to details of bugs caused by using `exit`?

Comment: After you fork but before you successfully exec you have two copies of everything that was in memory: two copies of every output stream that's about to be flushed when you exit, two copies of every cleanup function registered with `atexit` that's about to get called when you exit.  What `_exit` typically does is to exit *without* performing any of those cleanup activities.

Comment: @immibis What Steve said. Imagine, for example, that the parent has written some security sensitive output to a stream and it's held in the stream buffer. The child closes that stream's file descriptor and opens a new file descriptor that gets the same number, say to a logging server. When you call `exit`, the `atexit` handler may flush the security sensitive output to the file descriptor that now points to the logging server. Oops. You just logged a secret. (Yes this has really happened.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can imagine that happening; I asked if you knew of any actual vulnerabilities (well, bugs) caused by it.